# Cassandra-2.2.3 : Repeatedly facing "writing large partition error" even after multiple repairs

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.2

We have a 6 node each 2 datacenter Cassandra cluster production environment setup. We encounter large partition warning. We ran 2 successful repairs, still this is not getting resolved. How can I analyze and fix this?

`BigTableWriter.java:184 - Writing large partition system_distributed/repair_history:rf_key_space:my_table (108140638 bytes)`

```
Mode: NORMAL
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 1171896
Mismatch (Blocking): 808
Mismatch (Background): 131
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed
Large messages                  n/a        11              0
Small messages                  n/a         0       48881938
Gossip messages                 n/a         0         113659
```

Answer (score 1):

The `system_distributed.repair_history` table is not one that you really need to concern yourself with.  Unfortunately, this can happen when a lot of repairs have been run.  With 2.2, the only real solution is to `TRUNCATE` that table every now and then.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I am going to truncate it. Any chance this might impact future repairs?

Comment: @JikkuJoyce no, this table acts as a tracking mechanism for repairs, but has no bearing on future repairs run.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, truncated the repair_history and its fixed  We used to get this same error for system/hints. We used to run repair to fix it, going forward seems like we can truncate it using nodetool.